# Isolating $x$ in $\;-2 \ln x \leq y\;$ in two ways gives different results

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

> Let's say I want to leave $x$ alone in this inequality: $$-2 \ln x \leq y$$ where $x,y \in \Bbb R$.

Well one way of doing it is first dividing the $-2$ by both sides --> $$\ln x \geq -\frac{1}{2}y$$ and then taking $e$ and raising it to the power of the left and right hand sides --> $$x \geq e^{-\frac{1}{2}y}$$

---

But another way of leaving $x$ alone is by first using the power rule of the natural log function: $a\ln b = \ln (b^{a})$, thus we have --> $$\ln (x^{-2}) \leq y$$ and then taking $e$ and raising it to the power of the left and right hand sides --> $$x^{-2} \leq e^{y}$$ and finally raising each side to the exponent $-\frac{1}{2}$ --> $$x \leq e^{-\frac{1}{2}y}$$

---

I guess my question is what did I do wrong haha.

Comment: Raising both sides to a negative exponent causes reciprocation, which flips the inequality. Eg, $2<3$ becomes $2^{-1}>3^{-1}$.

Comment: You can use \ln instead of \text{ln} to produce $\ln$.

Comment: @Blue boom thank you.

Comment: @Gary awesome, that'll save some time haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For strictly-increasing $h,$
$$f(x)<g(x)\implies h\big(f(x))<h(g(x)\big).$$
For strictly-decreasing $h,$
$$f(x)<g(x)\implies h\big(f(x))>h(g(x)\big).$$